# Student visa to tourist visa in France

Tags: visa, france

So I'm currently in France on a student visa.  Can I stay in France under a tourist visa (for 3 months under the Schengen policy) if I decide to stop studying?

Answer (score 3):

Time spent under a long-stay visa (including student visas) does not count toward the 90-day maximum stay in the Schengen area. This rule is defined in article 5 for the Schengen Borders Code ([regulation EC 562/2006](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=CELEX:32006R0562)):

> Periods of stay authorised under a residence permit or a long-stay visa shall not be taken into account in the calculation of the duration of stay on the territory of the Member States.

Consequently:

- If you don't need a visa (see [the list of “annex II” countries on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area#Visa_exemptions)), you can indeed stay for another 90 days in the Schengen area.
- If you do need a visa for short stays, you could in theory come back to France immediately on a Schengen visa but you would first need to go somewhere else to apply and wait for this visa. Depending on your circumstances, getting this visa might prove difficult.

See also [this question on the travel sister site](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/does-tourist-visa-90-days-apply-after-a-working-holiday-visa-ends-in-schengen/24777#24777).